# Can't write data as nested maps to Firestore in Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I need a database structure that consists of nested maps such as the following example:

[image]

The upper map structure is: (key: "referrals", value: (key: userId, value: aBooleanValue))

So I used the following code to accomplish the result above:

```
let userId = ...
let aBooleanValue = ...

database.(...).setData(["referrals": [userId: aBooleanValue]])
```

But the code above causes an array inside of a map like the figure below instead of a nested map:

[image]

Any ideas how I could get rid of the array here?

**EDIT:** It's my bad. I was modifying the database as an array in another part of the app. So there is no bug here. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `referrals` to be a key in the map then you must first declare the map, which you never do. The above code, btw, gave me a map, not an array. But the map was named `referrals` and its only key was `userId`. Regardless, to make `referrals` a key itself, define the parent map:

```
Firestore.firestore().document("test/test").setData([
    "containerMap": [
        "referrals": ["user1": true, "user2": true],
        "contacts": ["user5": true, "user7": true]
    ]
])
```

Comment: I modified your code as following since I don't want a container map:

Firestore.firestore().document("test/test").setData([
            "referrals": [
                "user1": true,
                "user2": false,
            ],
        ])

Now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, it's my bad. I was modifying the database as an array in another part of the app. So there is no bug here. Sorry.